# How to pass two view model parameter in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, loops

I try to pass view model parameter to javascript function.but i send two parameter javascript function is not work.what it happen ??Please answer me !!!
in HTML

```
 @if (Model != null)
                {
                    int no =1;
                    for(int i =0; i<Model.purchaseOrderItemVMs.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        var count = i+1;
                        var ss = Model.purchaseOrderItemVMs[i].StockID;
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @no
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.purchaseOrderItemVMs[i].StockNo)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.purchaseOrderItemVMs[i].StockNo)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.purchaseOrderItemVMs[i].StockID, new { @id = "hidstockid" })
                            </td>                           
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.purchaseOrderItemVMs[i].Amount)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.purchaseOrderItemVMs[i].Amount)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" onclick="myFunction(@count,@ss)" value="Edit"/>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Delete", new { id = Model.purchaseOrderItemVMs[i].StockID }, new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-danger", @id = "btnDelete" })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        no++;
                        }
                    }
```

In Javascript

```
function myFunction(count, ss) {
         alert(ss);       
     }
```

Comment: One parameter is ok !!.

Comment: Hi all !!, i worte var ss = Model.purchaseOrderItemVMs[i].StockID; is ok ??. That variable is not work. what it happen ??  Please answer me !!! Thank !!

Answer (score 1):

Replace onclick function syntax, insetad of:
`<input type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" onclick="myFunction(@count,@ss)" value="Edit"/>` write the following code:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" onclick="myFunction('@count','@ss')" value="Edit"/>
```

It should work

Comment: Hi wekerle !!, i worte var ss = Model.purchaseOrderItemVMs[i].StockID; is ok ??. That variable is not work. what it happen ?? Please answer me !!! Thank !!

Comment: when you write: "alert(ss);", what apears there? or when you use the console of the browser to debug, what is the ss value?

Comment: I can't call javascript function when i pass the ss value !!

Comment: onclick="myFunction('@count','@ss')" ... have you written like this?

Comment: have you tried what value is in your ss variable? something like this: `<td>
                                @ss
                            </td>`